# How to disable GCC warnings for multiple library files in Keil?

Tags: c, gcc, keil, gcc-warning, pragma

I know that you can write a `#pragma` directive at the beginning of the file to disable warnings, for example: `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-variable-declarations"`. But this disables only one warning.
How can I disable all warnings for a specific file?

One possible way to solve this problem is to add a path to the system directory using the compiler option `-system`. But this method is not suitable because the Manage Run-Time Environment automatically connects library files using the `-I` option and overrides `-isystem`.

Comment: Don't these warnings tell the _compiler_ how to handle _source code_? And isn't the usage of libraries a _linker_ issue? I don't understand your problem, please [edit] your question and elaborate. A [mre] would be good. -- Note, warnings are necessary to put the finger on questionable code. Don't switch them off, correct the source.

Comment: I don't know where it is better to write an answer, in a separate answer or comment.
I needed to hide the warnings in the Keil project. Solution: in the Project window, click RMB on **Target** and select **Options for Target** (Alt+F7). Next, open the **C/C++** tab and select the line No Warnings in the **Warnings** drop-down list. This way we will disable all warnings in the project.
Next, select the file whose errors should be displayed in the project window. Click RMB on this file, select **Options for file**, go to the **C/C++** tab, select All Warnings in the **Warnings list**.

Comment: It seems that you need to take the [tour] to learn how this site works. If you have solved your issue, you can write an answer. A comment is the wrong place. -- However, you have not clarified your issue, so your question is not _that_ useful.